# Round imageview in UICollectionViewCell after setting cell size with UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am using an imageview in a UICollectionView cell. I am  setting size of cell with help of UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout. I want the image to be round properly but it form ellipse. After moving back from other viewcontroller it becomes round. My code is

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let yourWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/2.0 - 10.0
    let yourHeight = yourWidth
    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return totalCard.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColCell", for: indexPath) as! ColCell
    cell.imgMain.image = UIImage(named: "temp.png")
    if (self.totalCard.count-1) == indexPath.item {
        cell.lblTitle.text = "Add link"
        cell.imgMain.image = UIImage(named: "addCard.png")
    }else{
        cell.lblTitle.text = mediaTmp.cardName
        let url = URL(string: mediaTmp.cardImage)
        cell.imgMain.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.imgMain.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgMain.frame.height/2
    }
    return cell
}
```

I try to reload collectionview data but no use.

Answer (score 0):

#### try this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, canMoveItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let yourWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/2.0 - 10.0
    let yourHeight = yourWidth
    return CGSize(width: yourWidth, height: yourHeight)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return UIEdgeInsets.zero
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return totalCard.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ColCell", for: indexPath) as! ColCell
    cell.imgMain.image = UIImage(named: "temp.png")
    if (self.totalCard.count-1) == indexPath.item {
        cell.lblTitle.text = "Add link"
        cell.imgMain.image = UIImage(named: "addCard.png")
    }else{
        cell.lblTitle.text = mediaTmp.cardName
        let url = URL(string: mediaTmp.cardImage)
        cell.imgMain.kf.setImage(with: url)
        cell.imgMain.layer.cornerRadius = cell.imgMain.frame.height / 2


        cell.imgMain.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.imgMain.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    }
    return cell
}
```

###### and

#### Add this code in *Cell.Swift*

```
class CSCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var imgMain: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var lbl: UILabel!
    
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
           super.awakeFromNib()
           // Initialization code
       }
       
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
            super.draw(rect)
            self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2
        }

    
}
```